# C++ - Initialiser list for unordered_map of class method function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I'm new to C++11 so I have been experimenting with `std::function` today and I'm trying to use it to create a hash table for strings to class function pointers for a small assembler I am creating:

assemble.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Assembler {

    public:

    // Assembles the source file and writes it
    bool assemble(std::string output_file);

    // Creates the symbol table from a (.s) file
    bool create_symbol_table(std::string file_name);

    private:

    // Hash table for opcode to functions
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<bool(std::vector<std::string>)>> 
    opcode_map =
    {
     {"add",assemble_data_processing}
    };

    bool assemble_data_processing(std::vector<std::string> instruction);

};

bool Assembler::assemble_data_processing(std::vector<std::string> instruction) {
    std::cout << "Data Processing" << std::endl;    
    return false;
}
```

This gives me a compile time error with g++:

`g++ -Wall -g -Werror -std=c++11 -o assemble.o assemble.cpp`

`assemble.cpp:28:5: error: could not convert ‘{{"add", ((Assembler*)this)->Assembler::assemble_data_processing}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::function<bool(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)> >’
     };
     ^`

But if make the function a non-class function then it compiles without problems:

```
bool assemble_data_processing(std::vector<std::string> instruction) {
    std::cout << "Data Processing" << std::endl;    
    return false;
}
```

How can I initialise the `unordered_map` in a brace initialiser list for class methods?

Comment: Did you intend for `assemble_data_processing` to be a static member function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::bind`

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<bool(std::vector<std::string>)>> 
opcode_map =
{
 {"add", std::bind(&Assembler::assemble_data_processing, this, std::placeholders::_1}
};
```

Or a lambda

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<bool(std::vector<std::string>)>> 
opcode_map =
{
 {"add", [this](std::vector<std::string> instruction){return assemble_data_processing(instruction);}}
};
```

Or make your function static.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::function` cannot hold non-bound member functions.

You have three ways to fix this depending on the circumstance.

a) If `assemble_data_processing` does not use any member data, make it a static member function, and call it a day.

b) If your cache is associated with a single `Assembler` instance, then bind the function using `std::bind`, using something similar to:

```
opcode_map =
{
 {"add",std::bind(&Assembler::assemble_data_processing, this, _1)}
};
```

c) if the `Assembler` instance is something that gets determined later, then you will have to ditch `std::function`, and use a good-old function pointer to member function.

Comment: I think I was a bit misleading with my original source code. I do instantiate an `Assembler` object later on. The `assemble_data_processing` instruction was meant to be private however it did not use member functions so I guess it could have been a static function. The lambda expression suggested by December above seems to solve the problem.